# Drupal hiding the title in a node if it's <none>

Tags: php, drupal, title

I'm trying to figure out how to hide the title of my nodes in drupal... I don't wanna use another module, I just want to change something in the node.tpl.php...

My attempt was to ask if the title is "" and if not, it should just post the title... I've did it like this:

Damn won't work to show the code here, got it in jsfiddle now: jsfiddle.net/8d6FR/

But it doesn't work. Has someone some suggestions why it won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code looks almost right, I've changed it slightly just to make it easier to understand:

```
<?php if($title!="<none>"){ print render($title_prefix); ?>

<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h2>

<?php print render($title_suffix);} ?>
```

If that is not working then add the code:

```
var_dump($title!="<none>")
```

That will let you know how PHP is evaluating your if statement and will allow you to do some further debugging.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the quick answer... It says that the statement is true, although my title is "<none>"... Don't know why this is happening... Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: HA! I got it :-) I just changed the <none> to &lt;none&gt; ... I thought that drupal might not use utf-8 there and so I just tried it out and boom it works :) Thank you for fixing the code though! I think without the repositioning of the "!" it wouldn't work :-) Thank you!

Comment: I just realized that I could've used "none" instead of "<none>" ... Although it's safer to use <none> because someone might want to use "none" as a title :D

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

PHP in a JSFiddle, that is not gonna work :)...To hide your node titles you'll have to modify your tpl file indeed, or create one if it you need it for a certain content type or node, or manage the display of your nodes within Drupal admin. You may need [Title](https://drupal.org/project/title) to replace title field with a regular field in order to hide it with the "Manage display" interface or [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds).

Find your node.tpl.php or page.tpl.php (depends on your theme) using Theme Developper, and find something like print $title.

Comment: It's not in jsfiddle to "work" or something. It's just there to show the script. And if you read that, you'd see that I already found the $title and tried to put it in an if statement...